# Parallelizing openssl AES-128-CBC Serial Code

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openssl, openmp

I am trying to parallelize the following code:
The Serial code is:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int success = 0;

void handleOpenSSLErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

unsigned char* decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv ){

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    unsigned char *plaintexts;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    unsigned char* plaintext = malloc(ciphertext_len);
    bzero(plaintext,ciphertext_len);

    /* Create and initialise the context */

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleOpenSSLErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
    * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
    * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
    * is 128 bits */

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);

    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
    * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
    */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleOpenSSLErrors();

    plaintext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
    * this stage.
    */

    // return 1 if decryption successful, otherwise 0
    if(1 == EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)){

        success = 1;
        plaintext_len += len;
    }

    /* Add the null terminator */
    plaintext[plaintext_len] = 0;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    //delete [] plaintext;
    return plaintext;
}


size_t calcDecodeLength(char* b64input) {
    size_t len = strlen(b64input), padding = 0;

    if (b64input[len-1] == '=' && b64input[len-2] == '=') //last two chars are =
        padding = 2;
    else if (b64input[len-1] == '=') //last char is =
        padding = 1;
    return (len*3)/4 - padding;
}

void Base64Decode( char* b64message, unsigned char** buffer, size_t* length) {


    BIO *bio, *b64;  // A BIO is an I/O strean abstraction

    int decodeLen = calcDecodeLength(b64message);
    *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(decodeLen + 1);
    (*buffer)[decodeLen] = '\0';

    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(b64message, -1);
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    //BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Do not use newlines to flush buffer
    *length = BIO_read(bio, *buffer, strlen(b64message));
    BIO_free_all(bio);
}

void initAES(const unsigned char *pass, unsigned char* salt, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv )
{
    //initialisatio of key and iv with 0
    bzero(key,sizeof(key));
    bzero(iv,sizeof(iv));

    EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_128_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, pass, strlen(pass), 1, key, iv);
}


int checkPlaintext(char* plaintext, char* result){

    int length = 10; // we just check the first then characters
    return strncmp(plaintext, result, length);

}

int main (void)
{

    // password 12345
    // it took 9 seconds to work out
    char* ciphertext_base64 = (char*) "U2FsdGVkX19q3SzS6GhhzAKgK/YhFVTkM3RLVxxZ+nM6yXdfLZtvhyRR4oGohDotiifnR1iKyitSpiBM3hng+eoFfGbtgCu3Zh9DwIhgfS5A+OTl5a4L7pRFG4yL432HsMGRC1hy1RNPSzA0U5YyWA==\n";

    char* plaintext = "This is the top seret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";
    char dict[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // changed

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len, dict_len;

    // cipher (binary) pointer and length
    size_t cipher_len; // size_t is sizeof(type)
    unsigned char* ciphertext;

    unsigned char salt[8];

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    Base64Decode(ciphertext_base64, &ciphertext, &cipher_len);

    unsigned char key[16];
    unsigned char iv[16];

    unsigned char plainpassword[] = "00000";
    unsigned char* password = &plainpassword[0];

    // retrive the slater from ciphertext (binary)
    if (strncmp((const char*)ciphertext,"Salted__",8) == 0) { // find the keyword "Salted__"

        memcpy(salt,&ciphertext[8],8);
        ciphertext += 16;
        cipher_len -= 16;

    }

    dict_len = strlen(dict);

    time_t begin = time(NULL);


    for(int i=0; i<dict_len; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<dict_len; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dict_len; k++)
                for(int l=0; l<dict_len; l++)
                    for(int m=0; m<dict_len; m++){
                        *password = dict[i];
                        *(password+1) = dict[j];
                        *(password+2) = dict[k];
                        *(password+3) = dict[l];
                        *(password+4) = dict[m];


                        initAES(password, salt, key, iv);
                        unsigned char* result = decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_len, key, iv);

                        if (success == 1){
                            if(checkPlaintext(plaintext, result)==0){

                                printf("Password is %s\n", password);

                                time_t end = time(NULL);
                                printf("Time elpased is %ld seconds", (end - begin));

                                return 0;
                            }

                        }

                        free(result);
                    }


    // Clean up

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();


    return 0;
}
```

The parallel version is:

```
int main(void)

{
    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len, dict_len;

    int total_thread, thread_id;
    double start_time, end_time;

    unsigned char* ciphertext;
    unsigned char* ciphertextnew;
    size_t cipher_len;
    /* A 128 bit key */
    unsigned char key[16];
    unsigned char iv[16];

    unsigned char salt[8];

    char* ciphertext_base64 = (char*) "U2FsdGVkX19q3SzS6GhhzAKgK/YhFVTkM3RLVxxZ+nM6yXdfLZtvhyRR4oGohDotiifnR1iKyitSpiBM3hng+eoFfGbtgCu3Zh9DwIhgfS5A+OTl5a4L7pRFG4yL432HsMGRC1hy1RNPSzA0U5YyWA==\n";
    char password[5] = "00000";
    char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext =
        (unsigned char *)"This is the top seret message in parallel computing! Please keep it in a safe place.";

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    Base64Decode(ciphertext_base64, &ciphertext, &cipher_len);

    // retrive the salt from ciphertext (binary)
    if (strncmp((const char*)ciphertext,"Salted__",8) == 0) { // find the keyword "Salted__"

        memcpy(salt,&ciphertext[8],8);
        ciphertext += 16;
        cipher_len -= 16;

    }
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Starting of the program, start_time = %f\n", start_time);

    dict_len = strlen(alphabet);

    /* decrypt the ciphertext */
    decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_len, key, iv);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, 16);

    #pragma omp parallel shared(password_found,flag_found)
    {
        char password[5] = "00000"; //this is a thread private variable

        // These will be done in parallel
        #pragma omp for collapse(3)
        for (int s = 0; s < dict_len; s++)
        for (int t = 0; t < dict_len; t++)
        for (int u = 0; u < dict_len; u++)
        {
            password[0] = alphabet[s];
            password[1] = alphabet[t];
            password[2] = alphabet[u];

            // For every s,t,u, a single thread will loop through these
            for (int v = 0; v < dict_len; v++)
            for (int w = 0; w < dict_len; w++)
            {
                password[3] = alphabet[v];
                password[4] = alphabet[w];

                initAES(password, salt, key, iv);
                unsigned char* result=decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_len,key, iv);

                if (checkPlaintext(plaintext,result)==0)
                {
                    printf("\n%s", password);
                    printf("\nHere is the correct key!\n\n");

                    flag_found=1;
                    strcpy(password_found,password); // Copy thread-private copy to shared variable

                    // Now, signal everyone to stop
                    #pragma omp cancel for
                }

                printf("\n%s is bad\n", password);

            } // end inner group of loops

            // Threads will check here is they should stop
            #pragma omp cancellation point for
        } // end of the outer group of loops
    } // end of parallel region
     // Do something now //
    if (flag_found){
        printf("\nThe password is %s\n",password_found);
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("Password not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
// Clean up
EVP_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, instead of 12345(correct serial code password) I keep seeing 355555 in the parallel version.

I am actually new to openmp, how I arrived at the above code is due to different community and online research, but I still don't get the full implementation of the system. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The first race condition I already see in `initAES`. It writes to `key` and `iv`, which seem to be shared. There may be more of this in the rest of the function calls. Maybe it works if you use `firstprivate` on all of these variables and then let the thread that is successfull write its result to a shared variable. If I understand this right only one thread will ever enter the conditional upon having success so at least you wont need a critical section there (It's probably still better to have one for easier debugging, it shouldn't cost performance when not being entered).

Comment: Also you seem to have another question with the same code. Are they independent? If not, please delete one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide, I will delete the other one as this is much more updated.